# How do I pivot mutliple columns in a datasheet and create a bar chart off the results from the binomial count in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, pivot

I have a dataset that looks like

```
        Baseball|Basketball|FootBall|Soccer|State
Player 1       1           0        0     1    NY
Player 2       1           1        0     0    CA
Player 3       1           1        1     1    NY
Player 4       0           0        0     1    MA
```

I would like to create a graph or worksheet in my dashboard that would show

```
Baseball   3
Basketball 2
Football   1
Soccer     3
```

Also have it be dynamic so that if i change the filter to CA it would adjust

```
Baseball    1
Basektball  1
Football    0 
Soccer      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your data:
[image]

In Power query, you need to select the columns Baseball, Basketball, Football, Soccer, and select the [Unpivot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) option, which should give you something like this, with two new columns 'attributes' and 'value'
[image]

I've renamed attributes 'Sports'

Once you have done that, you can create a basic measure

```
Sports Total = SUM('Table'[Value])
```

You can then slice and dice the data by whatever you like
[image]